# PHP - $x=0 -- Why is it passing off as being equal to 1?

Tags: php

I have a few lines of code

```
$case=0;
file_put_contents("text.txt", $case, FILE_APPEND);
if ($case = 1)
{
    $message['a']="co"; 
}
if ($case = 0)
{
    $message['a']="to";
}
echo $message['a'];
```

It will echo "co".  Why is this?  The file_put contents puts "0".  However the if statement thinks it is 1 for some reason...

Comment: You need to use ` == ` for both if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in `if` condition. You doing assign instead of comparison. 
So here is the solution.

```
$case=0;
file_put_contents("text.txt", $case, FILE_APPEND);
if ($case == 1)
{
    $message['a']="co"; 
}
if ($case == 0)
{
    $message['a']="to";
}
echo $message['a'];
```

Comment: ha ha ha - its a race to get the same answer out  @Md. Sahadat Hossain :))

Comment: You have no idea how mad you just made me.  I've been freaking getting so pissed off with the constant thoughts. "WHY YOU NO WORKS?!?!?!?!"  Well, turns out I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the comparison operator "==" when comparing values: otherwise you are assigning values (in this case you were assigning $case to be 1 and then the message was "co".

```
$case=0;
    file_put_contents("text.txt", $case, FILE_APPEND);
    if ($case == 1)
    {
        $message['a']="co"; 
    }
    if ($case == 0)
    {
        $message['a']="to";
    }
    echo $message['a'];
```